# как сохранять загруженные файлы в react-native+expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

пишу приложение react-native + expo. сделал загрузку картинки/mp3 и вывод/проигрывать его на экран, но файл как я понял не сохранился в папке приложения. 
как сохранить файл в папке приложения?
Загружаю файлы

```js
for (i = 0; i < ways.length; i++) {
            const x = await Axios.get(`/v1/way/view?access-token=${token}&id=${ways[i].id}`);
            
            if(x.status == 200) {
                for( j = 0; j < x.data.stations.length; j++) {
                    await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
                        `${URL}${x.data.stations[j].soundLink}?access-tkoen=${token}`,
                        FileSystem.documentDirectory + `${x.data.stations[j].id}.mp3`
                        ).then( ({ uri }) => { console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri); } )
                        .catch( error => { console.log(error) })                
                }       
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй родную библиотеку

```
import { FileSystem, Constants, Notifications } from 'expo';
FileSystem.downloadAsync(
   "www.example.com/name.file",
    FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'name.fie'
)
   .then(({ uri }) => {
        console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
    })
     .catch(error => {
         console.error(error);
     });
```

Comment: а как скачивать файлы не указывая имя файла(сохранить исходное имя файла)?

Comment: так же, можешь распарсить строчку, вытащить из нее имя файла и подставить как аргумент

Comment: вытащил имя файла но теперь не создается директория в которую пытаюсь сохранить файлы. ошибка записи

Comment: отредактируй вопрос, покажи  в коде как ты это делаешь. А вообще если есть возможность уходи с expo